# Asp .net Core 3.1 transforming ClaimsIdentity with multiple AuthenticationScheme

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've faced a problem while implementing a couple of authorization schemes in ASP .Net Core application. Lets say they are declared like this in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      AuthenticationBuilder builder = services
                .AddAuthentication()
                .AddBasicAuthentication(o => { o.Realm = "MyRealm"; })
                .AddApiKeyAuthentication()
                .AddBearerToken(opt => { });
}
```

Each of these schemes provide its own implementation of **AuthenticationHandler** returning **ClaimsIdentity** if succeeded. But in each case the structure of claims are incosistent, i.e. ApiKeyAuthentication may return **ClaimsIdentity** with business-sensitive data stored in claim "api_service" while BearerTokenScheme will store it in a claim "sub", and I dont have control over this. So if I would like to use this information in a controller to associate some process with a service which have called my api method, I have to implement some complicated logic that would analyze current **ClaimsIdentity**, its auth scheme and set of claims.
Instead I would like to implement some sort of tranformation of ClaimsIdentity into **MyServiceClaimsIdentity** which would expose claims in a handy way so I can utilize them easily in my Controllers code:

```
public class MyServiceClaimsIdentity: IIdentity
{
    private readonly ClaimsIdentity innerIdentity;
    public Guid? UserId {get; }
    public string UserName {get; }
    public string ServiceName {get; }

    public MyServiceClaimsIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        this.innerIdentity = identity;
        TransformClaimsIntoProperties();
    }

    private void TransformClaimsIntoProperties()
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

I've tried to implement some sort of "transformative" **AuthenticationHandler** which would produce **MyServiceClaimsIdentity** after all other handlers would produce their ClaimsIdentity.

```
public class FinalAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<FinalAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        public FinalAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<FinalAuthenticationOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var identity = new MyServiceClaimsIdentity(this.Context.User.Identity);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, this.Scheme.Name);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }
```

Too bad at this point **this.Context.User.Identity** doesnt have any information of an user, so I'm confused where to put this tranformation logic or how would I get current ClaimsIdentity provided by other Handler in my **FinalAuthenticationHandler**. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After additional exploration I guess implementing IClaimsTransformation is the right place for such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing IClaimsTransformation and registering it as a Singleton did the job just fine

```
internal sealed class ClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, IClaimsHandler> handlersMap;

        public ClaimsTransformation(IEnumerable<IClaimsHandler> handlers)
        {
            if (handlers == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handlers));
            }

            this.handlersMap = handlers.ToDictionary(t => t.SchemeName);
        }

        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            if (!(principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Principal.Identity is of type {principal.Identity.GetType()}, expected ClaimsIdentity");
            }

            if (!this.handlersMap.TryGetValue(principal.Identity.AuthenticationType, out var handler))
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException($"Scheme of type {principal.Identity.AuthenticationType} is not supported");
            }

            var result = new ClaimsPrincipal(handler.Handle(claimsIdentity));
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
```